# How highlight text with spacing in Unity without TMP #mark tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I highlight text with spacing in Unity like in this picture

[image: text layout that I want to achieve]

I've used a TMP mark tag, but it doesn't work the way I would expect it to, it ends up drawing on top of the text instead of behind it, and it can't be resized

I've tried: `<mark=#006CFFaa>100</mark>`

Resulting in:

[image]

The text is not bright, as if the highlight is all over the text, but it has become more transparent

Also is there a way to make the corners rounded as in the picture?
Maybe other methods than TMP?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've tried, otherwise it's a bit hard to provide a 'fix'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the following result:

[image: Mark]

using the following code:

```
  GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "Text <mark=#ffff00aa>can be marked with</mark> an overlay"
```

As the length can be controlled; nevertheless, as stated [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/RichTextMark.html), this effect is overlaid.

**UPDATE 1:**

if you don't want to use TMP, I think you can put a image behind each word, but right now I cannot think of a way to make it dynamic. it would yield some result like this:

[image: using Image]

**UPDATE 2:**
what if you put two text mesh pros on top of each other, and marker down the one on the back. it gives reuslts like this:

[image: UPDATE 3]

Comment: i use <mark=#ffff00> without "aa", i now check your variant

Comment: the last two numbers are for transparency.

Comment: i know, but i use numbers, not double a symbols, I checked but main text, Still darker than unselected color, I need #006CFF. Also can there be a way to make rounded? May be other methods not TMP

Comment: I edit question, please check

Comment: do you need it to be dynamic?

Comment: "put a image behind" - no, it's localized text and it can change its size depending on the language. I would like to put an image on the back, can this be done through the Custom Editor?

Comment: I had another idea and updated the answer, see if it resolves your problem

Comment: wow, it so interesting, im now check this, but I still can't round the corners =(

Comment: Can I add padding left/right/up/down to the mark,

Comment: I think these additional options are not avalible for this tag. you can read more here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/RichText.html, if I could find a solution, I'll update it.

Comment: Thanks, im take your variant, its genius solution